What happened to Desperado Publishing?
For those of you who are unfamiliar with it, Desperado Publishing is a comic book company founded by comic book writer Joe Pruett in the summer of 2004. It was an imprint/subsidiary company of Image Comics from 2004 to 2007. Desperado apparently broke away from Image Comics and operated independently (from 2007 to 2009) and IDW Publishing acquired Desperado Publishing as a new imprint/subsidiary company in 2009.
It seems that they stayed in business up to 2013 since they actively published several "art of" books from their stable of artists. The strange part is that after March 2013, they seem to have disappeared.
I checked the company's official website (desperadopublishing.com), and it has been sold to a website holding company. I checked the address with Wayback Machine and it seems that they put the site up for sale in 2013 before it turned into that.
Does anyone know what happened to Desperado Publishing?

Not an answer as I'm busy and don't know a lot about it, but Wikipedia is way out of date on this one. Their Facebook page seems to have gone quiet in 2014, the last post pointing to Caliber Comics, maybe some of the writers/artists went there...?

Since their former website is now held by a dubious-looking spammer, I've removed the active link.

The obvious possibility is "failed business".  As to why?  No idea.  However Joe's wikipedia page says that he cofounded AfterShock Comics in 2015.  So maybe you could ask him directly?

It's referred to in the past tense here; "In 2004, Joe founded Desperado Publishing, which had publishing partnerships with Image Comics and IDW." - https://www.alphapublisher.com/post/aftershock-comics. I strongly suspect that it's a dead duck.
